# Stop ASP.NET from handling 404 errors for files with extensions (not IIS)

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I'm using IIS7 and ASP.NET. Basically building a simple CMS and need to handle .htm and .html file extensions (served by dynamic asp.net pages).

I have it setup so IIS7 passes the page to asp.net (not the static handler); however, ASP.NET knows the file doesn't exist and redirects to its 404 (404.aspx?aspxerrorpath=xx) before I can do what I need to with it (parse teh url and display the correct page).

I'm using IIS7 url rewrite module to do the rewtitting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might be what you are looking for, although I'm not sure:

http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/745738.aspx